# Filter Django queryset by related field (with code-value)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Simplifying my model a lot, I have the following:

```
class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.IntegerField()


class Statistic(models.Model):
    '''
    Known codes are:
        - goals
        - assists
        - red_cards
    '''

    # Implicit ID
    player = models.ForeignKey(
        'Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statistics')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

I'm using a code-value strategy to add different statistics in the future, without the need of adding new fields to the model.

Now, I want to filter the players based on some statistics, for example, ***players who scored between 10 and 15 goals***.

I'm trying something like this:

`.filter('statistics__code'='goals').filter('statistics__value__range'=[10,15])`

but I'm getting duplicated players, I'm guessing because that `value__range` could refer to any Statistic.

How could I properly filter the queryset or avoid those duplicates?

And how could I filter by more than one statistic, for example, ***players who scored between 10 and 15 goals and have more than 5 assists***?

By the way, note that the *value* field (in Statistic) is a string, and it will need to be treated as an integer in some scenarios (when using __range, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ***chain the `filter`***. Use the **`filter()`** method only once with ***`distinct()`*** method.

```
.filter(statistics__code='goals', statistics__value__range=[10,15]).distinct()
```

**NOTE:** I can see few quotes around *statistics__code* and *statistics__value__range*, no need to put that.

Comment: What about filtering by two statistics, for example, players who scored between 10 and 15 goals and have more than 5 assists?

Comment: Then the querying becomes a *complex* one and in such situation, you must use the **`Q(...)`** expression

Comment: Plus I just realized that the value is always a string, so the __range won't work as expected...